# C++ Gets Identifier Not Found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

In my old C++ project I use to use the gets() command. I've done my research and noticed that it is not reliable anymore and my project won't run with using it.

I use this bit of code right here:
Load(gets(new char[50]));

How would I now get this line of code to work properly? And if you could provide an explanation.

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: Also consider using temporary variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews getline does not work with the "new char"

Comment: You can find some alternatives to `gets` in this question, but @ThomasMatthews is correct, use modern C++ replacements rather than trying to patch up old code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: @SirRyan98 you don't need to use `new char` with those. You can convert `std::string` to a chararcter array with `.c_str()`.

Comment: @SirRyan98:  Apparently, you haven't done enough research on [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: @Saustin I am now confused on what to remake my above code.

Comment: Please review the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
std::string text;
std::cout << "Enter some text to load: ";
std::getline(cin, text);
Load(text.c_str());
```

If you must use character arrays, here's a code fragment:

```
const size_t ARRAY_CAPACITY = 64U;
char text[ARRAY_CAPACITY];
std::cout << "Enter some text to load: ";
cin.getline(&text[0], ARRAY_CAPACITY);
Load(text);
```

Comment: I get an error of text that states "argument of type "const char ^" is incompatible with perimeter of type "char ^"

Comment: For which line in which example?  BTW, you never posted the declaration for `Load`.

Comment: Always post error messages verbatim.  There are no perimeters in C++, only with closed shapes. :-)